# FORTRAN: out of bounds check fails in subroutines?

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine, intel-fortran

I have a rather simple piece of code (reduced to the essentials from bigger program).

I pass an array and the size of the array to a subroutine. I get no error if the passed size does not match the actual size of the array. And I can even manipulate the parts of the array that don't "exist" !!! (I overwrite memory that I shouldn't overwrite).

Here is the subroutine:

```
subroutine sub(arr, narr)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: narr
double precision, dimension(narr) :: arr
integer :: j

do j = 1, narr
  ! print all the values
  write(*, &#39;(&quot;Arr[&quot;,I0,&quot;] = &quot;,f0.10)&#39;) j, arr(j)
  ! change the values
  arr(j) = -10d0
enddo

end subroutine
```

and here the main program

```
program main

implicit none

integer, parameter :: narr = 5
! the array is made smaller
double precision, dimension(narr - 2) :: array

integer :: j

! assign values to array
array = (/ (1d0*j,   j = 1,narr - 2) /)

! print using the subroutine
print*, &quot;inside subroutine&quot; 
call sub(array, narr)

! print outside the subroutine
print *, &quot; &quot;
print *, &quot;outside subroutine&quot;
do j = 1, narr
  write(*, &#39;(&quot;Arr[&quot;,I0,&quot;] = &quot;,f0.10)&#39;) j, array(j)
enddo

end program
```

If I compile with ifort and "-check all" it only catches the error in the main program, but not in the subroutine.

Is there a way to catch also the error in the subroutine ?

Comment: This is not a bug, but a _feature_ of `FORTRAN`. Anyway, I agree that morern compilers should be able to to check for this and here Intel does not produce a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Declare array as `dimension(:)` in the subroutine -- assumed-shape array.  Using this Fortran >90 declaration requires that the procedure interface be known to the caller -- the easiest way is to have the procedure in a module and `use` that module in the caller.  You don't actually need to pass the size of the array to the subroutine -- you can determine it as `size(arr)`.  I have left the argument `narr` to retain the bug.

```
module MySub

contains

subroutine sub(arr, narr)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: narr
double precision, dimension(:) :: arr
integer :: j

do j = 1, narr
  ! print all the values
  write(*, '("Arr[",I0,"] = ",f0.10)') j, arr(j)
  ! change the values
  arr(j) = -10d0
enddo

end subroutine

end module MySub


program main

use MySub

implicit none

integer, parameter :: narr = 5
! the array is made smaller
double precision, dimension(narr - 2) :: array

integer :: j

! assign values to array
array = (/ (1d0*j,   j = 1,narr - 2) /)

! print using the subroutine
print*, "inside subroutine"
call sub(array,narr)

! print outside the subroutine
print *, " "
print *, "outside subroutine"
do j = 1, narr
  write(*, '("Arr[",I0,"] = ",f0.10)') j, array(j)
enddo

end program
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The original routine is in a module, so no problem there, but I diliberatly did not want use assumed-sized arrays in subroutines. I hoped the compiler then tells me, that I pass a wrongly sized array. Is there a way to have this feature or would I have to check "size(arr) == narr" manually?

Comment: If you tell the compiler that an array has size `narr`, it will take your word for it, whether or not you are right.  It is less work and less error prone to use an assumed-size array and  not to explicitly pass an argument for the size.   I recommend using the Fortran >=90 method and using assumed-size arrays and the intrinsics such as `size`.